# Nintendo Switch Family Plan: Against TOS to add friends?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-switch-online

A friend of mine wants to crowd source the cost of a family membership. We are not in the same household, and I can't find anything in the TOS that restricts members to an actual household. Is there any specific documentation of Nintendo ALLOWING friends to make a family group?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I once asked to Nintendo about that, and they replied:

> ご連絡いただいた件でございますが
> 「ファミリープラン」に加入（購入）したニンテンドーアカウントの「ファミリー」全員が「Nintendo Switch Online」のサービスをご利用いただけます。
>
> また、下記いずれの場合も、同じ「ファミリー」になることが可能です。
>
> ・同居していない人のニンテンドーアカウント
>
> ・異なるNintendo Switch本体に登録されているニンテンドーアカウント
>
> ※複数のファミリーに属することはできません。
>
> 仕様上、弊社ではご家族であるかどうかの判別はできないため可能ですが、トラブル等が発生した場合、弊社では一切の対応を行うことができません。
>
> ご家族間でファミリーを構成されることをお勧めいたします。

Let's translate vital part...

> It is possible to be a member of the same "family" in any of the following cases:
>
> ・ A Nintendo Account of a person who does not live in the same household.
>
> ・ Nintendo accounts registered on different Nintendo Switch consoles.
>
> *It is not possible to belong to more than one family.
>
> This is possible because due to the nature of the service, we are unable to determine whether or not a person is actually a member of their family. However, in the event of any problems, etc., we will not be able to take any action to resolve the issue.

This means that they doesn't allow or disallow it, just saying it's possible. So, I've decided to take advantage of it, and ever since I'm "family" with friends, for 3 years straight, with zero problem.

Comment: _It is not possible to belong to more than one family._ Well, yes.  I would think.

Comment: Technically I'm member of two family, thanks to Nintendo... :p

Comment: @TimmyJim In the real world, many people do, and this technical limitation causes problems for them. (At least Nintendo's being _reasonable_ about it, unlike [some Netflixes I could name](https://www.theatlantic.com/ideas/archive/2023/02/netflix-streaming-password-sharing-family-household/672967/).)

Comment: So do I, thanks Nintendo